# Checking null and "emptyness" in Java (Android) --> crash

Tags: java, android

I made an if/else statement that checks if the value of an Edit Text (the value of the Edit Text is saved in `myPrefs`) is empty. If it is empty, there will show up an error. If it is not empty, another dialog will show op and the user can go further in the app. So that is what I want.

The problem is, when I'm checking whether it is empty or not, the app crashes.
This is my code, I already implemented the `||` (with `null` and `isEqual("")`, but that didn't work out.

```
if (myPrefs.getString("TELHUISARTS", null).equals("") || myPrefs.getString("TELHUISARTS",null).equals(null)) {
    String contactWithQuotes = getResources().getString(R.string.Contactwithquotes);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Gevaar.this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder2.setTitle("No phone number found");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder2
        .setMessage("You have not entered a phone number for your GP. You can do this at " +contactWithQuotes+ ".")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setNegativeButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
                // the dialog box and do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

    AlertDialog alertDialog2 = alertDialogBuilder2.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog2.show();
} else {
    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

The error:

```
05-01 23:17:09.295  24300-24300/com.company.myapp 
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.company.myapp, PID: 24300
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.company.myapp.Gevaar$11.onClick(Gevaar.java:609)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the logcat/error

Comment: Your EditText is called myPrefs?

Comment: @Kay I assume that this is a `SharedPreferences` object due to the name and `getString` method.

Comment: @Kay it is a sharedpreferences where the value of the edittext is saved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to change your condition from:

```
 if (myPrefs.getString("TELHUISARTS", null).equals("") || myPrefs.getString("TELHUISARTS",null).equals(null))
```

To:

```
 if (myPrefs.getString("TELHUISARTS",null) == null || myPrefs.getString("TELHUISARTS", null).equals(""))
```

The way you did it, if `myPrefs.getString("TELHUISARTS",null)` is indeed `null`, you will get a `NullPointerException` in the first check, since it would be equivalent to calling `null.equals("")`. Also, you should use `==` instead of `equals()` to check if a reference is `null`.

Comment: If its null he would also get NPE in the second check. How does the order matter?

Comment: @Kay Both the order and the way they check for `null` matter. If the OP were to replace `equals` with `==` but do not change the order they would get a `NullPointerException` anyway.

Comment: myPrefs.getString("TELHUISARTS", null).equals("") statement will execute in both the scenarios. If its null NPE will be thrown in both scenarios. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kay The `||` operator will short-circuit if the first condition is `true`, so the second condition will not be executed.

Comment: @Anderson - Thanks! I had forgotten about this with time.. <3 so i.e. y

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `myPrefs.getString("TELHUISARTS", null).equals("")`

do

`"".equals(myPrefs.getString("TELHUISARTS", null))`

because `"".equals(null)` return false
and `null.equals("")` crash, because did on a null object

Comment: This is a good suggestion overall, but in this case it will still throw a `NullPointerException` in the second condition if `myPrefs.getString("TELHUISARTS", null)` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

In **Android SharedPreferences**,

```
myPrefs.getString("", "")
```

From `getString()` method the second parameters is defined to get if there is no any value set with current key.

So in your case,

You have to first check weather your preference `myPrefs` is **NULL** or **not** if its not NULL then only get String from it with key  `TELHUISARTS`.

So in your case your if condition should be,

```
if(myPrefs == null || myPrefs.getString("TELHUISARTS", "").equals(""))
```

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the [second parameter of the getString() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) is to account for situations where `getString()` returns `null`, so that you avoid `NullPointerException`s. As such, I would not personally pass `null` as a argument. Instead, I would write something like this:

```
private static final String FAIL_CODE = "here_comes_the_fail_train";
private static final String GET_STRING_PREF= "telhuisarts";

if (myPrefs.getString(GET_STRING_PREF, FAIL_CODE).equals(FAIL_CODE)) {
                    //You returned a null value, so you can account for it here...
```

Comment: This is the best approach IMO.